# Require ClojureScript's Analyzer API

Tags: clojurescript

I'm having trouble requiring ClojureScript's analyzer API:

```
(ns triangle.core                               
  (:require
   [cljs.analyzer.api :as ana-api]))
```

yields:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo : No such namespace: cljs.analyzer.api, could not locate cljs/analyzer/api.cljs, cljs/analyzer/api.cljc, or Closure namespace "cljs.analyzer.api" in file ...
```

Anybody knows, what could be the reason? Requiring cljs.analyzer works without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, are you using the latest version?

Comment: oh, that was the thing. a 'new' figwheel template came along with an old cljs version. thx!